# Explanation of assembly code in x86

Tags: c, assembly

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   char a[5];
   char b[10];
   strcpy(a,"nop");
   gets(b);
   printf("Hello there %s. Value in a is %s.\n",b,a);
   exit(0);
}
```

The first few lines of assembly output show:

```
push %ebp
mov %esp,%ebp
sub $0x28,%esp
mov $0x80c5b08,%edx
lea -0xd(%ebp),%eax
mov (%edx),%edx
mov %edx,(%eax)
lea -0x17(%ebp),%eax
mov %eax,(%esp)
call 0x8049c60 <gets>
```

I'm confused for a few reason. First, why do we do `sub $0x28,%esp` which accounts for 40 bytes if `char *argv[]` accounts for 8 bytes, `int argc` accounts for 4, `a` accounts for 8, and `b` accounts for 12 -> 8+4+8+12 = 32?

I'm also struggling to see where strcpy happens and what accounts for the two memory addresses `$0x80c5b08` and `0x8049c60`.

Comment: When dumping to assembly, you have the option of viewing in **AT&T** format (default) or in **Intel** format. Some (me included) find the **Intel** format much more readable. It is controlled with the `-masm=intel` option. E.g. `gcc -S -masm=intel -o yourfile.asm yourfile.c`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks. I'm really struggling to understand what's happening in the assembly. If you have any explanation I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Jason , you can't expect to learn anything if you ask all your h.w question in this site. Try to read on/offline and understand yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I'll give you what I can, but my assembly is a bit rusty. First, let's start with what you are looking at. With AT&T syntax, you basically have to read the address operation backwards (`operation data register`) compared to Intel syntax (`operation register data`) which is part of the reason some people prefer to read Intel.

The assembly calls are not too difficult to digest from an overview standpoint. If you look at the first two commands, the first pushes the previous `base pointer` address onto the stack to save it. (when this program exits, the previous base pointer address will be restored and that is where execution in the calling routine will pick back up). The second line moves the `base pointer` address for this program to the `current stack pointer` address (top of the stack) to start executing your program. Both lines are known as the `assembly prolog`.

```
push %ebp
mov %esp,%ebp
```

The next line `subtracts 40 bytes (28 hex)` from the `stack pointer` (the stack grows lower) to create space for the local variables `a` and `b` where the "nop" data and the resuts of `gets` will be copied. I'm not sure what precice alignment it is trying to achieve, but the storage for `a` will be 5 bytes and `b` 10.

```
sub $0x28,%esp
```

The following line moves the pointer address `0x80c5b08` to the general purpose `dx` register (`edx` for 80386 32-bit registers). In assembly, you put the address of the data you want to manipulate into one of the CPU registers, before you do something with it. Here it looks to be putting the memory address for "nop" in `edx`.

```
mov $0x80c5b08,%edx
```

The next call `lea` **loads the effective address** copies the memory address (at offset) `base pointer - 14` (0xd hex) bytes into the `eax` register. The beginning address to `a` so that the string "nop" can be copied there.

```
lea -0xd(%ebp),%eax
```

The following calls to `mov` copy the data pointed to by `edx` to the memory location specified in `eax`. copying "nop" to `a`.

```
mov (%edx),%edx
mov %edx,(%eax)
```

The next `lea` loads the memory address for `base pointer - 23` (0x17 hex) `b` into `eax` and the `mov` places the address on the stack before the call to `gets` fills the memory at that location.

```
lea -0x17(%ebp),%eax
mov %eax,(%esp)

call 0x8049c60 <gets>
```

Afterwards, there with be instructions to load the memory addresses for `a` and `b` along with the address for the static part of the string to string before calling `printf`. Hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some padding after the local variables
    as there needs to be (32-bit aligned) room for the parameter for `gets()` 
    and the PC register that will be saved via the call instruction.

Note: the `ebp` register has to point to the next available stack address
    after the local stack frame.

Note: the `gets()` function should never be used, 
    for several reasons.  Use `fgets()` instead.

The `strcpy()` was replaced by the compiler, with a macro invocation.
    that macro produced the following:

```
mov $0x80c5b08,%edx
lea -0xd(%ebp),%eax
mov (%edx),%edx
```

> I'm also struggling to see where `strcpy()` happens and what accounts for the two memory addresses $0x80c5b08 and 0x8049c60"

The 0x80c5b08 is the address of the literal that is to be copied into the variable.

The 0x8049c60 is the linked address of the `gets()` function.

Comment: What happens after the strcpy() then? the last 3 commands before gets()?